# Private CocoaPod - module not found even though pod installed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, podspec

I've created a new framework `CocoaPod`, here's a copy of my 'podspec' file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

# 1
s.platform = :ios
s.ios.deployment_target = '12.0'
s.name = "IdFramework"
s.summary = "IdFramework is a framework containing functionality."
s.requires_arc = true

# 2
s.version = "0.1.0"

# 3
s.license = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }

# 4 - Replace with your name and e-mail address
s.author = { "Idan Israel" => "myEmail" }

# 5 - Replace this URL with your own GitHub page's URL (from the address bar)
s.homepage = "link"

# 6 - Replace this URL with your own Git URL from "Quick Setup"
s.source = { :git => "{link to my framework on Github}",
             :tag => "#{s.version}" }

# 7
s.framework = "UIKit"
s.dependency 'Firebase'

# 8
"IdFramework/**/*"

# 9

# 10
s.swift_version = "4.2"

end
```

'podspec' uploaded successfully, I can see the sources on `GitHub`.

I've created a new project, in which I'm trying to use my newly created `CocoaPod`. Here's what the `Podfile` look like:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '12.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source '{Link to my source code on GitHub}'

target 'TestingPods' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TestingPods
  pod 'IdFramework', '~> 0.1.0'

end
```

Here's the code I have inside the framework:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

public class FirebaseConfig {
    public static func setupFirebase() {
        let arguments = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments as [String]
        var plistFileName = "GoogleService-Info-"

        if let environment = arguments.first?.split(separator: " ").last {
            plistFileName += environment
            
            guard let plistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: plistFileName, ofType: "plist"), let options =  FirebaseOptions(contentsOfFile: plistPath) else {
                return
            }
            
            if FirebaseApp.app() == nil{
                FirebaseApp.configure(options: options)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `CocoaPod` and all its dependencies are installed correctly, I can also see `IdFramework` under `Pods` in `Xcode` - however, when I try to import `IdFramework` - I'm getting a `No such module 'IdFramework'` error message.

I tried the following:

1. `pod deintegrate` then `pod install`.
2. Checking the `Pods` under `Manage Schemes`, and building both projects.
3. Made sure that both `iOS version` and `Swift version` all match.
4. Cleaned my project entirely and rebuild.

None of the above worked for me, and the issue persists. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace #8 with:

```rb
s.source_files  = "IdFramework/**/*"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, however, when I do that, then I get an error message when trying to create the pod - validation fails not finding 'Firebase' - any idea why?

Comment: Don't know, sorry. Maybe try `pod repo update` and then retry, just to make sure.

Comment: Actually, I was able to to resolve that issue, but then another one came up - It me two errors, which are the same, about the Info.plist' file: 'Target 'IdFramework' (project 'Pods') has copy command from...' . I checked the 'Copy Bundle Resources' - there are no files being copied there ('Info.plist' was there before, but I removed it). Any clue?

Comment: Don't know, it's hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: I updated my question with my code - I have only one file in the framework for now. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I meant the whole thing - project and all. It's probably out of scope for a stackoverflow question - you may need to exclude some files, or add `preserve_paths`. A good resource is https://github.com/bielikb/xcframeworks .

Comment: Thanks, I'll try investigating the issue. Marking the answer as answered, cause it solve my initial question. Thanks.